# Маршалированный объект О_о

Tags: c#, .net

Платформа .NET класс Type имеет свойство "IsMarshalByRef", которое по словам MSDN "*Возвращает значение, позволяющее определить, маршалирован ли объект Type по ссылке.*" Это, к сожалению, мне ничего не говорит. Может кто-нить более доступно объяснить возвращаемое данным свойством значение? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Унаследован ли тип от MarshalByRefObject. Типы, унаследованные от этого класса, можно использовать так: в одном домене создаём экземпляр, в другом домене дёргаем методы этого экземпляра. Домены могут находиться на разных машинах. Называется технология .NET Remoting.